# iptables redirect via url to localhost vhost

Tags: iptables, http

I'm trying to set up a test environment for a mobile app. I have a machine acting as a gateway and providing dhcp on 192.168.10.0/24, and serving pages from apache.

How would I set up iptables rules so that any traffic coming from 192.168.10.0/24 gets redirected to my vhost by url- so url1 goes to host1, url2 goes to vhost2 and default everything else to vhost0?

I am only using http now, maybe i will add https later if everything else works.

Comment: It sounds like you need a reverse proxy, not iptables.

Comment: A reverse proxy, or a load balancer like [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with `iptables`. You can only operate on IP addresses with IPTables, not hostnames / URLs. You need a proxy such as what Apache allows you to do to redirect based on URL / vhost.